# How to fix colors glitch on iPhone 6 screen

Tags: iphone, ios

I got the iPhone 6 just after the release of the iPhone XS. Recently, my iPhone started to have "colors" on the screen. Here are some photos of it,

[image: Error1]
[image: Error2]
[image: Error3]

I have updated the software to the max I could update it to. (iOS 12.5)
Do I need to replace the screen?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, this looks like a hardware failure... You may want to consider purchasing a newer iPhone (there are reasonably priced second-hand models) Instead of replacing the screen: the iPhone 6 is not longer supported and you won't get any software updates for it.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for the information!